# walking through two tables (matrices) matching columns and applying a function in R

Tags: r, statistics

So I have two matrices. Lets name them controls and patients. Each row is a sample, and each column is a concentration of a certain protein. It looks like this:

```
        V1    V2    V3    V4     V5     V6    V7    V8    V9     V10    V11
sample1  1533.34  9.88  6.82 17.88  70.75 350.07 20.67 13.96 10.17  711.02 114.06
sample2  2311.30 12.74  6.82 17.88  80.71 505.96 34.36 19.66 18.70  863.70 181.43
sample3  1314.83 11.39 18.12 41.26 104.36 278.17 40.25 27.12 41.34 1100.00 160.83
```

This is just a small subset, I actually have more values. I want to compare this to another matching table by column. Side question, is it correct to use t-test in this case, assuming the data is normally distributed? Anyway. I've tried apply() function:

```
apply(controls,2,function(x) t.test(x, patients)$p.value)
```

And I am getting some results. But I have doubts if I used the function correctly. Does it matches two columns in two tables as it was meant to be? Or I used it incorrectly?

EDIT Oh yeah. It is definitely incorrect. As mean value for column in the second table always stays the same.

Comment: I am a bit confused about which way you want the comparison, by row or by column?

Comment: I want to compare two tables by column

Comment: ahh, I should've another argument(2) in my apply function(). But it is incorrect anyway. Ill edit the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 mapply(function(x,y) t.test(x,y)$p.value, 
         as.data.frame(controls), as.data.frame(patients))
 #       V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6        V7        V8 
 #0.8481788 1.0000000 0.4605294 1.0000000 0.6436604 1.0000000    1.0000000 1.0000000 
 #       V9       V10       V11 
 #1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

assuming that "controls" and "patients" are `matrix`

#### data

```
controls <- structure(c(1253, 2311.3, 1314.83, 9.88, 12.74, 11.39, 
20.8, 
6.82, 18.12, 17.88, 17.88, 41.26, 70.75, 53.5, 104.36, 350.07, 
505.96, 278.17, 20.67, 34.36, 40.25, 13.96, 19.66, 27.12, 10.17, 
18.7, 41.34, 711.02, 863.7, 1100, 114.06, 181.43, 160.83),
.Dim = c(3L, 
11L), .Dimnames = list(c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3"), c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11")))

patients <- structure(c(1533.34, 2311.3, 1314.83, 9.88, 12.74, 11.39, 
6.82, 
6.82, 18.12, 17.88, 17.88, 41.26, 70.75, 80.71, 104.36, 350.07, 
505.96, 278.17, 20.67, 34.36, 40.25, 13.96, 19.66, 27.12, 10.17, 
18.7, 41.34, 711.02, 863.7, 1100, 114.06, 181.43, 160.83),
.Dim = c(3L, 
11L), .Dimnames = list(c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3"), c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11")))
```

Comment: I've tried this. But it gives p-values of 1, for every column. Plus I've checked what t.test function returns in each case, and output seems a bit funny. So I am not sure if it does what it means to.

Comment: @YKY It means the t.test is not significant for the patient and control for each column, ie. not any difference for the concentration of protein

Comment: @YKY if you check the results from the data I used, it is not always `1` and I changed only a few elements for the control and patients.

Comment: Yeah. I've just read the description of mapply. I understand what p-val of 1 means. And it looks like you are right. But 1 for every single column confuses me a bit. If the results would be like 0.98 1 0.97 1 1 or something like this I wouldn't be suspicious.

Comment: @YKY Can you check the columns of each dataset to see if they are almost the same?

Comment: Oh. I am dumb. I've accidentally created two similar text tables with names patients and controls and did not notice it. Sorry.

Comment: @YKY It happens sometimes.  Now, you solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that "patients" and "controls" are `data.frame`, try:

```
results <- dplyr::summarise_each(patients, funs(t.test(., controls$.)$p.value))
```

Comment: I'll report when I will install the package on mac. Turns out that x11 is no longer included.

Comment: @YKY Well, it should give you exactly the same results as akrun's answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a bit of trouble parsing your question, but I might have an answer.

If you're looking for the column-wise match rate between two equivalently-dimensioned matrices, there's a very simple way to do that:

```
colMeans(controls==patients)
```

To find the absolute number of matches between the matrices:

```
colSums(controls==patients)
```

Comment: I want to apply specific function for each column of two tables I have. Suppose I have two tables of the identical size. With column names: V1, V2, V3 etc. I was wondering how can I use one of apply() functions family so I will not have to manually type t.test(table1$V1, table2$V1) each time.